# iOS Enterprise License for deployment to clients

Tags: iphone, ios, enterprise, iphone-developer-program

The company that I work for develops a suite of workforce management software, which we then license and distribute within large organisations. The idea is to create a mobile component of the software suite to target iPhone and iPad. Originally we assumed that if we were to purchase an Enterprise Developer License from Apple we would be able deploy to our clients. From what I have read though, it would appear that you are only licensed to deploy the app to your organisation and not to your clients. Has anybody had any experience with something similar? What are the options? Do we have to deploy it through the appstore? or is there some way where we can control deployment to our clients?

Thanks

Jacob

Comment: What you want is the 'b2b' service under the Volume Licensing (Business & Education) section. For more information, see: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

This is not really a programming question, tho.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple enterprise program distribution questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034495/apple-enterprise-program-distribution-questions)

Comment: @rishi no my question is different :) B2B seems to be what we want, though it's unavailable in Australia which kinda sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: the Enterprise distribution program specifically disallows sharing your apps outside of your own company. How about the [Volume Purchase Program for Business](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/)?

> Businesses can discover, purchase, and distribute apps in volume to their entire workforce.
>
> ...
>
> Provide unique, tailored solutions directly to business customers who are enrolled in the Volume Purchase Program.

Comment: b2b looks like the way to go but it's unavailable in Australia.

Comment: I'm familiar with the predicament, I'm also based in Australia. Not sure why this got -1, though!

Comment: I'm not sure why it got a -1 either