# Why is the App Store and Ad Hoc button greyed out when I try to create a distribution certificate?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

So I am trying to submit my app to the app store. So my first step is to create a distribution certificate. However, it will not allow me to click the app store button (It is greyed out). Why is that?

I've uploaded another app earlier today and it has the status "upload received". I'm not sure if it's because there is a limit to creating distribution certificates while there is an app with this status.

I have 2 distribution type certificate, 1 APNS development and iOS development. I have read that there is a limit of 3 distribution certificates but could not find official documentation stating that. Is this true?

Answer (score 11):

Personally I've only ever been able to create two distribution certificates, so you're probably running into that wall as well. I found another post on StackOverflow here that has some useful information ([Apple enterprise program distribution questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034495/apple-enterprise-program-distribution-questions)). Here's what he said.

```
Two enterprise distribution certificate can be created at a time.
```

I can't find any official documentation though :P

Comment: So How can I distribute multiple apps with only one distribution certificate??

Answer (score 4):

Short: Revoke the oldest distribution certificate at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action and create a new one with a "CertificateSigningRequest" (you'll see) generated on your own computer. All provisioning profiles that used that certificate will be invalidated, this will probably affect ad-hoc builds (not Apple TestFlight or App Store) and enterprise distributed apps.

Long: If you want to keep the certificate (especially useful for teams with more than three people that wants to be able to upload builds, and enterprise distributions where all the apps might stop working on a revoke), you'll have to find the computer it was generated on and export the private key for the certificate that probably only exists on that computer, and import it on your own. Now you should be able to download the distribution certificate from the developer portal and use it as usual. See more: [No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381216/no-provisioning-profiles-with-a-valid-signing-identity-i-e-certificate-and-pri)

Comment: Will this effect the apps that are currently on the store?

Comment: According to [this source from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/), it only affects submission of new apps and updates. In my experience it also prevents TestFlight users from installing the app, though I don't have a source.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have only one distribution certificate per developer account.

*"A distribution certificate identifies your team or organization in a distribution provisioning profile and allows you to submit your app to the store. Only a team agent or an admin can create a distribution certificate."*

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html