# No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found

Tags: ios, xcode

Yes, I am aware of the numerous duplicates of this question, but I tried everything suggested by others. At this point I don't have duplicates, I revoked and regenerated the certificates and keys from the scratch, I have my certificates paired with the corresponding keys.

The problem that I am facing is as follows: if I try to have the release with a distribution profile in my build settings I keep getting the error specified in my header, having a development profile though, works and doesn't provoke any problems. In case, I continue with a development profile and create the archive, when trying to distribute it, I can not specify my distribution profile again as I keep getting **The private key for "" is not installed on this mac**.

For generating certificates and keys,I used xCodes Preferences -> Account. For my development certificate xCode downloaded the certificate on it's own, while the distribution one I had to download manually. It did as well download all the profiles for me as I can visualise them in my iPhone configuration utility.

The question is: Am I missing something for the distribution profile? The error message says: **No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings "" were found.** does this mean that I have to link my certificate with the profile somehow?

Comment: Well, it has to be admitted, Apple signing stuff is a big mess than give headhaches to lot of developers and is responsible to a lot of lost work hours. I started ios dev years ago and still have issues with that (especially when your work in a large team when the xcode "revoke and request" message box is evil)

Answer (score 3):

You should go to `KeyChain` Access and check if your distribution certificate contains a `private key`. If it doesn't, you need to regenerate your distribution certificate, the private key can't be retrieve from developer site, which means you have lost the key forever.

The distribution certificate should look like this:
[image]

Comment: "I have my certificates paired with the corresponding keys."

Comment: You may need refresh your developer account in Xcode->Preference->Account->View Details, also make sure the bundle id in your provisioning profile is the same with you app

Comment: "refresh your developer account in Xcode->Preference->Account->View Details" - this fixed it for me.

Comment: "*You may need to refresh your developer account.*"   Just to make life even more unbearable for us, Apple has removed the Refresh button in Xcode 7.1   Seriously, this development environment doesn't stop getting worse, year after year.   I spend more time fighting with Xcode (particularly when deploying in-house apps) than writing code.

Comment: Actually, as far as I've read, @MikeGledhill, they are refreshed each time you open the details dialog, or you hit the Download all button. Maybe not the most desirable, yep, but still…

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid signing certificate for distribution. You seem to have a signing cert only for development. When you can't figure what is wrong kn your own after a while: Delete your private development and dist keys from keychain (be sure to delete the private keys, these are the ones visible when you expand an item in the tree viw in keychain. otherwise it may delete the public key and just silently hide the private key). selete all provisioning profiles. and recreTe both provisioning and develop and dist signibg certs.

you will develop some skills kver time when dealing with this every day. though when you can't figure, just go the hard reset path.

Comment: Certificate is valid. Recreated from the scratch several times.

Comment: look in project overview if the correct team is selected, and in build settings if. correct dist certificate + distribution profile for release build is selected.